# Twitter bootstrap radio buttons not working

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

I got a problem with the twitter bootstrap javascript radio buttons. When I select one and then click the submit button, it doesn't show the selected radio value.

My code:

```
<form action="" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">Type:</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
          <button type="button" data-toggle="button" name="option" value="1" class="btn btn-primary">Option One</button>
          <button type="button" data-toggle="button" name="option" value="2" class="btn btn-primary">Option Two</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
      <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Go">
      <a href="index.php" class="btn">Back</a>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

As you can see, there is a `name="option" value="1"` and `name="option" value="2"` but when I select one radio and I do:

`<?php print_r($_POST); ?>`

There is no `option` post specified.

It happens only for the twitter radio buttons, because when I add `<input type="text" name="test" value="something"/>` then it will appear in the `$_POST` variable.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem is `<button>` doesn't submit anything when clicked. You will need to have a hidden input field, and trigger a value change within the input when clicking the button

```
<input type="hidden" name="option" value="" id="btn-input" />
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">  
  <button id="btn-one" type="button" data-toggle="button" name="option" value="1" class="btn btn-primary">Option One</button>
  <button id="btn-two" type="button" data-toggle="button" name="option" value="2" class="btn btn-primary">Option Two</button>
</div>

<script>
  var btns = ['btn-one', 'btn-two'];
  var input = document.getElementById('btn-input');
  for(var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById(btns[i]).addEventListener('click', function() {
      input.value = this.value;
    });
  }
</script>
```

In the case of the bootstrap the 'radio' only affects the button state & behavior. It doesn't effect the form behaviour.

Comment: This works great for me, complete with full implementation example.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 17):

This is a jquery alternative to the above piece.

```
$("body").find(".btn").each(function(){
    $(this).bind('click', function(){
      $("input[name=view-opt-bt-group-value]").value = this.value
    });
  });
```

The HTML to this is:

```
<div class="row pull-right">
  <div class="btn-group view-opt-btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
    <button type="button" class="btn" value="0"><i class="icon-th-list"></i></button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" value="1"><i class="icon-th-list"></i></button>
    <input type="hidden" name="view-opt-bt-group-value" value="0">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i think you want $("input[name=view-opt-bt-group-value]").val(this.value)

Answer (score 8):

You can add the `btn` class to `<label>`s, so I achieved the following which doesn't require a hidden input, degrades gracefully if no bootstrap or javascript and you can still use the html helpers.

[Try it out](http://jsfiddle.net/vYfzU/28/).

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
   <label class="btn">@Html.RadioButton("option", 1) Option 1</label>
   <label class="btn">@Html.RadioButton("option", 2) Option 2</label>
</div>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // Bootstrappable btn-group with checkables inside
        // - hide inputs and set bootstrap class
        $('.btn-group label.btn input[type=radio]')
          .hide()
          .filter(':checked').parent('.btn').addClass('active');
    });
</script>
```

**Update:** They're using this format now in Bootstrap 3 but it requires slightly different markup (namely `data-toggle="buttons"`). See http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons

Answer (score 3):

The simplest jQuery code I came up with was:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
    <button type="button" class="btn" onClick="$('#gender').val('f');">♀</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" onClick="$('#gender').val('m');">♂</button>
</div>
<input name="gender" id="gender" type="hidden" value="">
```

It's an exceptional use-case, for me, so it didn't need to be robust or flexible.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/16214643/1111662 by @mcNux

In your view (I use HAML but convert to ERB if needed)

```
.btn-group{data:{toggle: "buttons-radio"}}
  %label.btn
    = f.radio_button :gender, "Male"
    Male
  %label.btn
    = f.radio_button :gender, "Female"
    Female
```

In your view-specific javascript e.g. `pages.js.coffee` (again, I use CoffeeScript but convert to plain JS JQuery if needed)

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('.btn-group label.btn input[type=radio]')
    .hide()
    .filter(':checked').parent('.btn').addClass('active')
```