# Bootstrap radio button "checked" flag

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

In case #1 works, in case #2 it do not works. Check the code bellow:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h1>Radio Group #1</h1>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input name="radioGroup" id="radio1" value="option1" type="radio"> 1
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input name="radioGroup" id="radio2" value="option2" checked="checked" type="radio"> 2
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input name="radioGroup" id="radio3" value="option3" type="radio"> 3
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <h1>Radio Group #2</h1>
        <label for="year" class="control-label input-group">Year</label>
        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input name="year" value="2011" type="radio">2011
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input name="year" value="2012" type="radio">2012
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input name="year" value="2013" checked="checked" type="radio">2013
            </label>
        </div>  
    </div>  
</div>
```

You can see it in action here: http://bootply.com/84165

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Assuming you want a default button checked.

```
<div class="row">
    <h1>Radio Group #2</h1>
    <label for="year" class="control-label input-group">Year</label>
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" name="year" value="2011">2011
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" name="year" value="2012">2012
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-default active">
            <input type="radio" name="year" value="2013" checked="">2013
        </label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Add the `active` class to the button (`label` tag) you want defaulted and `checked=""` to its `input` tag so it gets submitted in the form by default.

Comment: Thanks @Trevor. The button is checked now, but when I submit the form, it doesn't understand it as checked. If I manually click in the others options without the 'active', the submit can understand the value. With 2013 active, if I click in 2011, for example, and click again in 2013 and submit the form it works. Do you have any ideia? Thanks again.

Comment: Looks like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11462434/twitter-bootstrap-radio-buttons-not-working

Comment: Oh in that case try adding the `checked=""` to the input element as well.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for that, it's a real forehead-slapper when you read it!

Comment: Thanks! One plus vote for you and one down for angular for the strange behaviour...

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 15):

A javascript fix to apply the 'active' class to all labels that are parents of checked inputs:

```
$(':input:checked').parent('.btn').addClass('active');
```

insert right after

```
$('.btn').button();
```

Comment: If you're having trouble with the buttons not being highlighted after hitting "Back", this snippet of JavaScript fixes that.  Thanks, @rawrkats.

Comment: I like this solution the best, but I used `$(".btn-group").find(':input:checked').parent('.btn').addClass('active');` so that it runs a touch faster on pages that don't have any of these.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use active in the label to make it work as mentioned above. But you can use checked="checked" and it will work too. It's not necessary but it's more legible and makes more sense as it is more html format compliance.

Answer (score 1):

Use **active** class with **label** to make it auto select and use `checked=""` .

```
   <label class="btn btn-primary  active" value="regular"  style="width:47%">
   <input  type="radio" name="service" checked=""  > Regular </label>
   <label class="btn btn-primary " value="express" style="width:46%">
   <input type="radio" name="service"> Express </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to use bootstrap radio to check one of them depends on the result of your checked var in the .ts file.

component.html

```
<h1>Radio Group #1</h1>
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons" >
   <label [ngClass]="checked ? 'active' : ''" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
     <input name="radio" id="radio1" value="option1" type="radio"> TRUE
   </label>
   <label [ngClass]="!checked ? 'active' : ''" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
     <input name="radio" id="radio2" value="option2" type="radio"> FALSE
   </label>
</div>
```

component.ts file

```
@Component({
  selector: '',
  templateUrl: './.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./.component.css']
})
export class radioComponent implements OnInit {
  checked = true;
}
```