# Bootstrap: show/hide content with html radio buttons

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button, navigation

Can anyone help me pointing out what am I missing in the following Twitter-Bootstrap 3 snippet:

```
        <fieldset>
                    <input type="radio" name="rbLogin" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#login-tab" />
                    <label for="login">Log in to my account</label>

                    <input type="radio" name="rbLogin" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#register-tab" />
                    <label for="register">Register for a new account</label>
        </fieldset>

        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane" id="login-tab">
                Login...
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="register-tab">
                Registration
            </div>
        </div>
```

Clicking any of the radio buttons acts as expected: the correct div is displayed and the other one becomes hidden. So far, so good. But the radio button does not get in checked state. How can I make this fully functional?

The client explicitly requested to not use raw javascript or jQuery code to hide/shown html content. This is my first Bootstrap project, so maybe this is a dumb question.

Was able to get this done with  elements instead of radio buttons, but the exact requirements contain radio buttons.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by this way:

```
<label data-toggle="tab" data-target="#tab-1">
  <input type="radio"> foo
</label>
<label data-toggle="tab" data-target="#tab-2">
  <input type="radio"> bar
</label>
```

and some js

```
$('label[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  $('input').removeAttr('checked').removeProp('checked');
  $(this).find('input').attr('checked','checked').prop('checked','checked');
});
```

I know it is not js-free solution, but better than nothing :)

Answer (score 0):

This will help you in having the radio buttons work properly :

[Bootstrap radio button “checked” flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102946/bootstrap-radio-button-checked-flag)

Comment: Thank you, but was not able to solve my problem based on the info from the link you specified :/ Looks like Bootstrap swallows the default event for the radio button if the radio button tag includes the "data-toggle" attribute. Not sure why.