# Replace bootstrap radio buttons with button-group

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the bootstrap `button group` to make my radio buttons look nicer as shown in the original documentation [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-checkbox-radio)

However there is a problem with the example because the radio button state does not coincide with the button .active state. The new button overwrites the radio buttons so it no longer change state to/from `checked`.

Seems like something obviously wrong with this so is there something I missed? Seems to be intentional by bootstrap!? We need the radio buttons to work too!
Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/philphil/g1yazzvc/4/) if it helps. You can see that `checked` isn't refected in the button state and clicking the buttons no longer adds `checked=checked` to the input.

I included jquery in the help tags because I guess there is a jquery workaround that can help me, but I would hope there is a native bootstrap setting for this!

Comment: If you use firebug in bootstrap web you can se that when the checkbox is clchecked the label <label class="btn btn-primary"> has the class .active, you can manage the event adding a id to the label and checking the classes

Comment: Thanks, I was wishfully hoping for a native bootstrap solution since it seems the example they provide is self defeating. I am not good with jquery either. and the form might already have `checked=checked` when it is loaded so I am not sure if that requires another event listener or not.

Comment: You can use firebug to see that in your example of JSFiddle

Comment: And here there is the same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102946/bootstrap-radio-button-checked-flag

Comment: will I have a race condition between setting `active` when `checked` and setting `checked` when button clicked?