# User should not be able to select the button which is already selected

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, button

Button group is not working as it should, the problem is if the "**ON**" is selected, it should not be selected again, but the problem is even the "ON" button is selected I am able to select the ON button again.

How can I stop my button to stop any action when the button is already selected.

This is my code for my **button group**:

```
<form action="myclass.php" method="post">
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-default btn-xs myOnbutton">
            // myOnbutton is the button name
            <input type="radio" autocomplete="off"> ON
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-default btn-xs myOffbutton">
            // myOffbutton is the button name
            <input type="radio" autocomplete="off"> OFF
        </label>
    </div>
</form>
```

Do anyone knows where I am making the mistake, so it is selecting the button again.

Comment: check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102946/bootstrap-radio-button-checked-flag

Comment: Where is php used? Why do you use `php` tag?

Comment: You want to disable the radio button after selection?

Comment: @user1234 Yes more or less the same, when the button is selected it should be disable to select again :)

Comment: if you have problem in grouping, you can use same `name` attribute in your input `HTML` but if you want inputs to be disabled, you can see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to disable the groups after first selection,you should use jquery like [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tgEwStOHwoQuIFhUkdhg) :

```
 $(".btn-xs :radio").click(function(){
  $(".btn-xs :radio").attr("disabled", true); //Disable all with the same name
});
```

and if you want to disable selected radio button only,[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EhUgDbozrOBcpbmGir7H?p=preview) :

```
$(".btn-xs :radio").click(function(){
  $(this).attr("disabled", true); //Disable all with the same name
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i do not want to disable the group, i want to disable the button after selecting ...

Comment: instead of `$(".btn-xs :radio").attr("disabled", true);` use `$(this).attr("disabled", true);` to disable selected button @ChristoferHansen

Comment: @ChristoferHansen your welcome, if it helped you,you can check my answer as a correct one, I updated my answer ;)

Comment: @ChristoferHansen if you be clearer about what you want maybe I can help you,can you create plunker or someother thing to show me what you have already?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86590/discussion-between-christofer-hansen-and-shirin-abdolahi).

Answer (score 0):

This is basic HTML. It has nothing to do with bootstrap, you just need to add names to the checkboxes so you cant select both.

```
<label class="btn btn-default btn-xs myOnbutton">
    <input type="radio" autocomplete="off" name="switch"> ON
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-default btn-xs myOffbutton">
    <input type="radio" autocomplete="off" name="switch"> OFF
  </label>
```